# Update callback when doc resource changes?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm using Google Docs API. How can I know when a file resource changes?

I don't want to repeatedly poll data.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be using the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive), which has replaced the Google Documents List API.

Right now, there is no notification system, but it is a feature we are working on. Polling the changes feed every few minutes is not too bad, but it is really not good in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a callback, I'm afraid. To avoid polling the file data, however, you could poll the metadata only and test the md5 checksum field to determine when the file has changed.

The md5 checksum field is located in `docs$md5Checksum` (JSON) or `docs:md5Checksum` (XML) in the document list entry for the file.